# The NetTcpPortSharing service won't start on my Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, service, windows-service

The NetTcpPortSharing service won't start on my Windows 7 installation, it says:

> Windows could not start the NetTcpPortSharing service on Local Computer. Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Perhaps the service is located in a different location than Windows thinks. I know I can change the binpath of the service using the `sc` command but I don't know the filename of the service and I also don't know how to find out where the binpath is currently pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following way of correcting the paths so that the service starts again:

Go to the following key in the registry editor:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetTcpPortSharing

Change `Description` from

> @C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.21006\ServiceModelInstallRC.dll,-8200

to

> @C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelInstallRC.dll,-8200

Change `DisplayName` from

> @C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.21006\ServiceModelInstallRC.dll,-8201

to

> @C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelInstallRC.dll,-8201

Change `ImagePath` from

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.21006\SMSvcHost.exe

to

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SMSvcHost.exe